# Found malcode in my webserver apache2

Tags: apache2, webserver

can someone pls tell me how bad the found malcode in one of my webserver is ?

I found it in public_html/outlet.

[here is the code pastebin](http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=Cme0vcjQ)

i deleted the directory and try now to search my logs.

thanks for your answer

tango2000

Answer (score 0):

It isn't evident how bad it is. However, the real bad part is that they were able to inject code into your server.

Since you don't know how did they do it, it doesn't matter that you deleted the folder that contained the script. The vulnerability is still there and they will hack you again eventually.